# Video upload in PHP REST API

Tags: php, rest, api, video

How can use a video in API request / response in core PHP REST API.

for example if images means we can convert base64 and send to server and save it as aimage. In this case how can pass the video from andriod / iOS to server.

Comment: you can send video directly without converting `base64`

Comment: like formdata ?

Comment: yes, using formdata